# Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO table error. What might be the issue?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

Right now i am trying to implement a data pipeline between S3 to RDS which is in Postgres. In S3 files are in csv format. When the copy activity runs it throws an error as below

```
errorStackTrace
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Error copying record at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:65) 
at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.runActivity(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:35) 
at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.CopyActivity.runActivity(CopyActivity.java:22) 
at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16)
at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) 
at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) 
at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) 
at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) 
at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0
```

I have looked at other solutions but none of those really provide a solution. Can you please help me ?

Comment: What is the syntax around line 65 in you javacode? Do you have any output from postgres' logs? Do you manage to get any data in or does it crash at the first line?

Comment: @MortenSickel This is a copy activity from amazon s3 to RDS postgresql. I do not have access to the program.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=703050#703050
similar issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=703050#703050